# :hover selector being detected even when behind another element

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, menu

So, on a page I'm making, I have a menu bar and a black box that changes color on hover. When I try to open the menu, and move the mouse over the black box (still in the boundaries of the dropdown), the drop down disappears and the black box :hover selector is called.

Basically, :hover is being detected when it's behind an element. I tried searching, but the only results I'm getting are how to force it to detect behind an element. I want to prevent that.

http://jsfiddle.net/yFD2E/13/

Important HTML:

```
<div class="menuBar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div> <!--End menu bar-->

<div class="center">
    <div class="buttonGroup">
        <div class="buttonMain">
            <p class="hover">Plot</p>
            <p class="show title">Plot</p>
            <a class="show inFront" href="#">Test</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

menubar.css:

```
.menuBar {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #E9523F;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #DA281F;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.menuBar ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    positoin: relative;
}

.menuBar ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.menuBar ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 0pxx 5px;
}

.menuBar ul ul li{
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}

.menuBar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FAE12D;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 17pt;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.menuBar ul li:hover ul {
    background-color: #DA281F;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #DA281F;
}

.menuBar ul li:hover {
    background-color: #DA281F;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #DA281F;
}

.menuBar ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}

.menuBar ul li li:hover {
    background-color: #FE3845;
}
```

buttons.css

```
.buttonMain {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    line-height: 400px;
}

.buttonGroup {
    height: 500px;
}

.buttonMain .hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: show;
    color: #FFF;
}

.buttonMain .show {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: show;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #AAF;
    opacity: 0;
}

.buttonMain:hover .show {
    opacity: 1;
}

.buttonMain:hover .hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

.inFront {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.title {
    line-height: normal !important;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 30pt;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle, just try to remove the fluff a little bit more next time :)

Comment: The two answers below have you covered, but you might want to take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index to get a better understanding of what's going on.  I'm really curious what the final effect of the center area will be.

Comment: My English teacher assigned us projects for a literature book we just finished reading. One of the projects was to make a website. Part of her grading rubric is to have animations and for it to look decent, so I'm just going to go crazy with CSS and Javascript to get as high of a score as I can (She's only an English teacher). Thanks for the link too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` will do the trick like following

```
.menuBar ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;  // Just changed the spelling of position
    z-index:1000;  // Added 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peqh662a/